# Clicking on a click box over a full div link?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have list of to-do tasks, which are made as divs, using the stretched link bootstrap class. Click on the each of the to-do task, opens up a modal with detailed view. However, those divs (to-dos) have checked button which needs to be able to clicked. Right now when you click the checkbox, modal opens and it can't be checked.

Can you help me with this issue?

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item"><div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-single"><input type="checkbox"><label></label></div></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">Name</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".to-do-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" class="stretched-link"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your input tag is not closed

Comment: Isn't input a self-closing tag?

Comment: Yes it is. But you can autoclose it adding a slash : <input type="checkbox" />

Comment: Ok.. Forget it. I just verified. It depends of your doctype. It's useless if you use html5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/9359945

Comment: `z-index:-1` for `.stretched-link::after` is what you want?

Comment: I did try setting z-index to -1, and while the checkbox is clickable now, modal doesn't open on any other area

Comment: @PetarBrković, the answer below should hopefully get you what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options based on information in the question:

- either put just the checkbox on a higher z-index than the modal... I did this for the first checkbox where you can check/un-check the checkbox but can't touch the text in the label
- or put the checkbox and it's label on a higher z-index than the modal... I did this for the second checkbox where you can select the label text and check/un-check the checkbox
- Added a light red color so that it is easy to observe the behavior...

**working snippet** below:

```css
.myCheckbox,
.complete-checkbox-clickable {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 21;
}

.stretched-link::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(238, 149, 149, 0.23) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-single">
          <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox">
          <label>(this is where you should put the label) </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">Name</li>
      <br/>
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-single complete-checkbox-clickable">
          <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox">
          <label>2nd checkbox </label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".to-do-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" class="stretched-link"></a>
</div>
```